# Error while running MRJOB on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mrjob, bigdata

I put the mrjob.conf file in /home directory and tried to run the job from command and I am getting this error:

> File "/Users/bimalthapa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob-0.4.6-  py2.7.egg/mrjob/conf.py", line 283, in conf_object_at_path
>       with open(conf_path) as f:
>   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mrjob.conf'

This is my command:

> python mr_statistics.py -c ~/mrjob.conf -r emr s3://bimalucmbucket/inputFile.txt --output-dir=s3://bimalucmbucket/output --no-output

What is correct way of placing mrjob.conf and correct command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python mr_statistics.py -r emr s3://bimalucmbucket/inputFile.txt --output-dir=s3://bimalucmbucket/output --no-output -c ~/mrjob.conf